# How to use setState with ssdp m-search discovery?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, ssdp

I am using SSDP search message to discover devices with connected same network but when i tried to call setState hooks inside client.on function I only get one device informations.

I initialized my state value in this way

```
const [deviceList, setDeviceList] = useState([]);
```

And create a function for the client to add deviceList as it is found

```
const getAllDevices = () => {

var Client = require('react-native-ssdp-remote').Client,
  client = new Client();

client.search('urn:dial-multiscreen-org:service:dial:1');

client.on('response', function (headers) {
  const url = new URL(headers.LOCATION);
  if (url != null) {
    if (!deviceList.includes(url)) {
      setDeviceList([...deviceList, url]);
    }
  }
});
};
```

and called this function inside useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
  getAllDevices();
  }, []);
```

There are 4 devices connected to same network and it goes into setDeviceList process 4 times but i can only get one device. Could you please support.

Thanks.

Comment: Your code seems to be ok. It looks like the problem that you are face on are related with the RN library called "react-native-ssdp" and not related with the `useState` hook. Do you already checked the library specs in order to get the correct way to obtain all client list?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, i checked the library and example usages (https://github.com/netbeast/react-native-ssdp/blob/master/example/client.js) It does not return all clients at once, it enters client.on every time when it found a device. For this reason i thought it might be related to useState.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of a race condition instead of a library issue.
Give it a try with using functional update on setDeviceList.

```
setDeviceList(deviceList => {
   return [...deviceList, url]
}
```

Comment: I was able to get the device list correctly when i implemented it this way. Thank you very much!